# Sql problems , Select from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

```
Student - CodS NameS 
Discipline - CodD NameD YearD 
Subscrib - CodD CodS
```

I want to see the names of the students that are subscribed in all of the Disciplines that are from year 2.

```
Select S.Name
From Student S
Where S.CodS in (Select Sub.CodS
                     From Subscrib Sub
                     where Sub.CodDisc in (Select D.CodDisc
                                         From Discipline D
                                         Where D.Year = 2
                                        ))
```

But this returns the Names that are in Disciplines from year 2. I want just the names that are in all disciplines from year 2.
Can someone help?

Thank you

Comment: MySql or Sql Server?

Comment: Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: Post some sample data

Comment: I have Student - (1 , John  ) (2, Mary ) (3,Hugo)
Subscribe - (1,1) (2,1)(3,1)(3,2)(1.3)
Discipline - (1,Maths,2)(2,Cience,2)(3.Robotics,3)
So i have 3 students in Math but one in Cience , i want to show only Hugo because Hugo is in Math and Cience , that are de disciplines from Year 2 .
John is also in to 2 Disciplines but one is from year 2 the other is grom Year 3

Comment: post sample for all the tables and tell us your expected output

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for each table and the expected sample output. It will be more easier to understand your requirement.

Comment: For the future you, that will have to look at these tables a year from now, change the column names to something meaningful. Do not be cheap on letters when it comes to identifiers.

Comment: @AlmeidaGarret You should edit your question with the sample data, not put it in the comments. In the future, when asking SQL questions, including table structures, sample data, expected output, and your own attempt(s) along with why they weren't successful (error or wrong output) is the best way to get a good response. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming convention seems very bad unless this is a language other than English. You don't need to try to conserve bits here. We're not using punch cards any more. Make meaningful column names.

Also, prefixes for data types (which is what I assume the D in `YearD` and the S in `NameS` is) are bad ideas. If you want to know the data type of a column, it's easy enough to find out.

```
SELECT
    S.NameS
FROM
    Student
INNER JOIN Subscrib SUB ON SUB.CodS = S.CodS
INNER JOIN Discipline D ON D.CodD = SUB.CodD AND D.YearD = 2
GROUP BY
    S.NameS
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Discipline WHERE YearD = 2)
```

Comment: I think the Year = 2 condition should also be in the group by query.

Comment: It gives me trouble in the group by , like Name is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry, corrected now. I must have been thinking about something else as I typed.

Comment: Yes it works ! thank u so much , im not english and the tables are not in english in my program so sorry for any mistake . Thanks again